# Python, some strings encoded after using json.loads - how to decode them?

Tags: python, json

I'm making a GET request to the Google+ API.  I believe that JSON is returned (although I'm not clear about this, see 'response body has following structure' [here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search)).  I use json.loads to convert the response into a python dictionary.

```
 import requests 

 payload = {'query':'celery', 'key':'api_key'}
 r = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?", params=payload) 

 my_dict = json.loads(r.text)
```

All this works fine, except it seems parts of the response remain encoded in ecma script (again not sure) as they appear as below:

```
 \u06a9\u0634\u0648\u0631\u0646\u062f. \u0627\u0632 \u0633\u0627\u0644\u0647\u0627
```

My question is how can I decode these strings?  And is it JSON that is returned from Google?

Thanks in anticipation,

Comment: The part of the response you posted is a unicode string in utf16.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - how can you recognise this from the string?

Comment: double byte after the \u :)

Comment: Ok, do you know how to decode them correctly so they display ok on a webpage?

Comment: They are double byte characters but they may not be UTF-16.. there are other double-byte encodings

Answer (score 0):

The string in your example is UTF16

Load it in a python shell like this:

```
s = u"\u06a9\u0634\u0648\u0631\u0646\u062f. \u0627\u0632 \u0633\u0627\u0644\u0647\u0627"
print s
کشورند. از سالها
```

To see it in a webpage, the webserver must send the correct encoding in the Content-Encoding header.

Comment: The question is about how to decode a UTF-16 string, or otherwise convert the response object content into a useful datatype, rather than what sort of string this is or how to print a string.

Comment: @Kudzu read the comments between me and the OP :) i was trying to clarify the content he receive. There's not a copy and paste solution here.

Comment: @PaoloCasciello hi thanks for the answer but i'm not sure that can be correct as other Farsi characters in the dictionary are rendered fine.  It is just some strings which appear as escaped unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

I find it much easier to simply use the `json` attribute of the `response` object than using `json.loads()`:

```
r = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?", params=payload)
my_dict = r.json
```

or

```
my_dict = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?", params=payload).json
```

for a more succinct version.

Note that for some reason, the [documentation on python-requests.org](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#json-response-content) incorrectly shows this as `.json()`, i.e. a method rather than an attribute. No idea why, but don't get confused by that.

Comment: Neither of those examples worked, I'm trying to convert json to a python dictionary.  Thanks anyway

Comment: Really? They worked for me in the interpreter -- even without an actual API key, I get 
`>>> my_dict
{'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'Bad Request', 'errors': [{'domain': 'usageLimits', 'message': 'Bad Request', 'reason': 'keyInvalid'}]}}`, which is a perfectly valid `dict` object.